# In TextInputLayout change the color of hint for single letter or alphabet

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

I have defined TextInputLayout programmatically in my Activity. I have added EditText inside that TextInputLayout, that to programmatically.

Now, I have to set the color of hint of that edittext. Here I just have to change the color of single alphabet of the hint.

```
Example - Hint is like, Firstname *. Here  i want to change the color of "*" to Red and remaining hint as black in color.
```

I have already tried Html and Spannable String, but both are not working for TextInputLayout.

For Spannable i did

```
SpannableString redSpannable = new SpannableString(red);
redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, red.length(), 0);
Spanned hint = Html.fromHtml(string + redSpannable);
etDefault[j].setHint(hint);
```

For HTML,

```
I used "font-color"
```

If anyone knows this, then share your opinion.

Answer (score 12):

As per the [Android Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197889),

> Setting the hint to the editText respects the span, but the label does
>   not float on focus.

```
editText.setHint(hint);
```

> Setting the hint to the textInputLayout ignores the span

```
textInputLayout.setHint(hint);
```

> TextInputLayout uses internal class CollapsingTextHelper to draw the
>   hint, which does not support spans.

And as they said,

> They have passed this defect on to the development team and will
>   update this issue with more information as it becomes available.

Comment: It still does NOT support spans :/

Answer (score 0):

In `TextInputLayout` change the color of hint for single letter or alphabet

```
String firstNameText ="firstName *";
Spanned redStar; 
String html = "<string style=\"color:firstNameText;\">firstName<span style=\"color:red;\">*</span></string>";

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.L) { 
   redStar = Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY); 
} else {
   redStar = Html.fromHtml(html);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you using just `SpannableStringBuilder` without `Html.fromHtml`:

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hint with first letter black");
CharacterStyle cs= new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black));
sb.setSpan(cs, 0, 1, 0);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_messages)).setHint(sb);
```

In this piece of code the first letter becomes black. If you would like it to be bold too, use this:

```
CharacterStyle cs = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
```

That just puts hint to `EditText`. There will be no floating text effect.

Comment: Thank for this. But this is not working for edittext of textinputlayout.