# How can we use two different colors in hint of an Text Input Layout

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

[image: I want something like this]

The asterisk at the end should be in red red color.
I have already tried it using html but it is not working for me

Comment: try spannable string

Comment: Not working for text input layout

Comment: Try with substring function

Comment: @PratikSinha yes  it's seems textinput has issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37076105

Answer (score 1):

put this code in your string and use this string in your layout's "TextInputLayout"

```
<string name="string_name">Manager on Duty<font color="#ff0000"><bold>*</bold></font></string>
```

and

```
android:hint="@string/string_name" in your layout
```

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest you using just SpannableStringBuilder without Html.fromHtml:

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hint with first letter black");
CharacterStyle cs= new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black));
sb.setSpan(cs, 0, 1, 0);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_messages)).setHint(sb);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656596/in-textinputlayout-change-the-color-of-hint-for-single-letter-or-alphabet)

Comment: ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_messages)).setHint(sb); 
why you are casting it to text view

Comment: This is just an example. Just use the .setHint(..) to the textview you need it for. Ex: textView.setHint(sb);

Answer (score 0):

```
TextInputLayout textInput = findViewById(R.id.textInput);
SpannableString wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Hello world*");
ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan1= new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan2= new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
wordtoSpan.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan,0,2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
// wordtoSpan.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan1,9,11,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
wordtoSpan.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan2,11,12,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//Start Index 4 and whole upto end index is 6+1 = 7
textInput.setHint(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: In my case its works very fine Try This One.  Happy Coding